# dynamically .htaccess RewriteBase (depending on URL part)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following lines in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} product
RewriteBase /product

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} promotion
RewriteBase /promotion
```

and like to merge them into something like this:

```
RewriteBase /%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Is it possible anyhow?

Comment: nope, I don't think so. You can check the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html